# Hyperledger Fabric CA authority attribute

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have a question about Fabric CA: if I apply attributes (information) into CA and later on if I want to change some attributes into CA, how do I do this?

Comment: Why the downvotes without explaining to the asking person more details or providing references?

Comment: Have you cross referenced documents from - http://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about changing the attributes of an identity that has already been registered with Fabric CA, then yes this is now possible on the latest version of Fabric CA.

See: https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html#modifying-an-identity